# slideshow and scroll menu work perfect with Firefox but act funny with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, scroll

I have a website that includes an image gallery that turns into a slideshow on click. The website is divided into 4 vertical sections and you navigate through it (jumping up/down from one section to the next) with a smooth scroll effect by clicking on the main navigation menu. 
Everything works perfect with Firefox, but when I open it with Chrome 2 major problems:
1. The page keeps bouncing up and down like a yo-yo whenever you're in the "projects" section. Click on "Projects" in the main nav menu and you will see what I mean.
2. The slideshow doesn't work properly. Click on "Artwork". Then click on any image. You'll see that if you do this in Firefox the navigation menu is hidden behind the slides. However, with Chrome they are in the front. I have set the Z-index of the slides with #slideshow img {z-index: 1000} so I really have no idea why this is happening.
You will find my website here:
http://ninetieschild.github.io/my-site/
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Issue:

```
$window.bind("scroll resize", function() {`
```

is wrong. It keeps auto executing continuously. 
As this statement is always true

```
if(scrollTop > $('#services').offset().top-$(window).height()+300 && scrollTop < $('#about').offset().top-$(window).height()+$('#cogs').height()){
```

transform functionality after changes window size/scroll so the function gets executed again.

What are you trying to accomplish? 
You just want to click on me menu and get scroll to that specific sections?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your explanation. If you open the website in Firefox you will see exactly what I want to accomplish. The website works perfectly on Firefox. So yes, it just scrolls up/down to the specific sections. I think you'd call it a smooth scroll effect. If part of the code is incorrect then how come it works perfectly in Firefox?

Comment: In chrome, the function binded on "scroll resize" is executed continuously. Apparently $('#cog1').css({ '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + (scrollTop/slowness*0.9) + 'deg)'}); and the rest css transformation, perform a windows resize that makes the function to call itself again.   If you open chrome developer tools and add breakpoints you will see it.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've never used Chrome developer tools...did you discover this by adding breakpoints? Do I need to know the exact location of the repeating function to do this? and do you have any idea why this happens only in one of the 4 sections?

Comment: Hello? I've tried to learn how to use Chrome developer tools and I still have no idea what exactly you're on about. Where is this line of code you mentioned? Which file is it in? How am I supposed to see it if I don't know where to add those breakpoints??

Comment: ???? this answer is completely useless so long as you don't tell me where you found that line of code...

Comment: I think the answer is incorrect. I deleted the statement you thought was always true, as well as everything that should happen if it's true, and it doesn't make any difference. page still bounces up and down.  thoughts?